# Files Created with itextsharp Locked

Tags: c#, itext

The file creates and emails just fine. But when I attempt to delete or modify it for an indeterminate amount of time thereafter I get the dreaded "Cannot access file because it is in use by another program" message.  I've seen it before with documents created in itextsharp, but it was because a PdfStamper was left open.  Not sure what it locking it now.  Tried using WhoLockMe to see what's going on but it doesn't work on Windows 7 X 64.  Tried using LockHunter but it just says that the file isn't locked by any processes.  The location of the file is limited to admins and I have confirmed no other admins are in the file when this occurs.

```
public string SubmitWeekly(string store, string techId, string date, WeeklyHeader header, string latLon, string device, List<CPEquipment> equipment)
    {
        PdfReader templateReader = null;
        PdfReader overFlowReader = null;
        PdfStamper templateStamper = null;
        PdfStamper overFlowStamper = null;

        try
        {
            string result = "Success";

            string year = date.Right(4);
            string footerText = string.Format("Submitted {0} near {1} on device {2}", date, latLon, device);

            string template = @"C:\Templates\WeeklyInspectionFormCombined.pdf";
            string overflowTemplate = @"C:\Templates\WeeklyInspectionOverflowForm.pdf";
            string newFile = string.Format(@"C:\Documents\{0}\{1}\Weekly Inspection {2} {3}.pdf", year, techId, store, date);
            string overFlowFile = string.Format(@"C:\Documents\{0}\{1}\Weekly Inspection Pg 2 {2} {3}.pdf", year, techId, store, date);
            string directory = string.Format(@"C:\Documents\{0}\{1}", year, techId);

            templateReader = new PdfReader(template);

            //Check for directory and create if doesn't exist
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

            templateStamper = new PdfStamper(templateReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));

            AcroFields templateFields = templateStamper.AcroFields;
            AcroFields overFlowFields = null;

            int equipCnt = 1;
            int attachCnt = 1;

            //Extract stand alone items from equipment list
            List<CPEquipment> seUnits = (from s in equipment
                                         where s.Serial == s.AttachedTo && s.Status != "ATTACHMENT"
                                         select s).ToList();

            //Extract attachments from equipment list
            List<CPEquipment> attachments = (from a in equipment
                                             where a.Status == "ATTACHMENT"
                                             select a).ToList();

            //Set header and footer info in new file
            templateFields.SetField("Store Number", store);
            templateFields.SetField("Technician", techId);
            templateFields.SetField("Week Of", date.WeekOf());
            templateFields.SetField("Street Address", stAddress);
            templateFields.SetField("City", stCity);
            templateFields.SetField("Comments", header.Comments + "\nTrained:\t" + header.Trained + "\nOn:\t" + header.Topics);
            templateFields.SetField("Footer", footerText);

            //Set security info in new file
            templateFields.SetField("WL", header.WL == "True" ? "Yes" : "No");
            templateFields.SetField("TL", header.TL == "True" ? "Yes" : "No");
            templateFields.SetField("CC", header.CC == "True" ? "Yes" : "No");

            //Set equipment lines in new file
            int maxLines = seUnits.Count > 20 ? 20 : seUnits.Count;
            while (equipCnt <= maxLines)
            {
                CPEquipment current = seUnits.ElementAt(equipCnt - 1);
                CPEquipment trailer = (from t in equipment
                                       where t.AttachedTo == current.Serial && t.AttachedTo != t.Serial && t.Status != "ATTACHMENT"
                                       select t).FirstOrDefault();
                templateFields.SetField("ModelRow" + equipCnt, current.Model);
                templateFields.SetField("SerialRow" + equipCnt, current.Serial);
                templateFields.SetField("StatusRow" + equipCnt, current.Status);
                templateFields.SetField("Tool TurnedRow" + equipCnt, current.ToolTurned);
                templateFields.SetField("Last PMRow" + equipCnt, current.LastPmDate + " " + current.LastPmHours);
                templateFields.SetField("Current HoursRow" + equipCnt, current.CurrentHours);
                templateFields.SetField("TagRow" + equipCnt, current.Tag);
                templateFields.SetField("StExpiresRow" + equipCnt, current.State + " " + current.Expiration);
                if (trailer != null)
                {
                    templateFields.SetField("Trailer ModelRow" + equipCnt, trailer.Serial);
                    templateFields.SetField("Trailer VINRow" + equipCnt, trailer.Model);
                    templateFields.SetField("TagRow" + equipCnt, trailer.Tag);
                    templateFields.SetField("StExpiresRow" + equipCnt, trailer.State + " " + trailer.Expiration);
                }

                equipCnt++;
            }

            //Set overflow lines if any
            if (seUnits.Count > 20)
            {
                overFlowReader = new PdfReader(overflowTemplate);
                overFlowStamper = new PdfStamper(overFlowReader, new FileStream(overFlowFile, FileMode.Create));
                overFlowFields = overFlowStamper.AcroFields;
                overFlowFields.SetField("Store", store);
                overFlowFields.SetField("Footer", footerText);

                while (equipCnt > 20 && equipCnt < seUnits.Count)
                {
                    CPEquipment current = seUnits.ElementAt(equipCnt - 1);
                    CPEquipment trailer = (from t in equipment
                                           where t.AttachedTo == current.Serial && t.AttachedTo != t.Serial
                                           select t).FirstOrDefault();
                    overFlowFields.SetField("ModelRow" + (equipCnt - 20), current.Model);
                    overFlowFields.SetField("SerialRow" + (equipCnt - 20), current.Serial);
                    overFlowFields.SetField("StatusRow" + (equipCnt - 20), current.Status);
                    overFlowFields.SetField("Tool TurnedRow" + (equipCnt - 20), current.ToolTurned);
                    overFlowFields.SetField("Last PMRow" + (equipCnt - 20),
                                            current.LastPmDate + " " + current.LastPmHours);
                    overFlowFields.SetField("Current HoursRow" + (equipCnt - 20), current.CurrentHours);
                    overFlowFields.SetField("TagRow" + (equipCnt - 20), current.Tag);
                    overFlowFields.SetField("StExpiresRow" + (equipCnt - 20),
                                            current.State + " " + current.Expiration);
                    if (trailer != null)
                    {
                        overFlowFields.SetField("Trailer ModelRow" + (equipCnt - 20), trailer.Serial);
                        overFlowFields.SetField("Trailer VINRow" + (equipCnt - 20), trailer.Model);
                        overFlowFields.SetField("TagRow" + (equipCnt - 20), trailer.Tag);
                        overFlowFields.SetField("StExpiresRow" + (equipCnt - 20),
                                                trailer.State + " " + trailer.Expiration);
                    }

                    equipCnt++;
                }

                overFlowStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                overFlowReader.Close();
                overFlowStamper.Close();
            }

            //Set attachment fields and update attachment in db
            foreach (CPEquipment attach in attachments)
            {
                templateFields.SetField("SNRow" + attachCnt, attach.Serial);
                templateFields.SetField("MR" + attachCnt, attach.Model);

                attachCnt++;
            }

            //Flatten forms and close readers and stampers
            templateStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            templateReader.Close();
            templateStamper.Close();

            //Set up email
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com"),
                                            new MailAddress(techMail));
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(newFile));
            if (equipCnt > 20)
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(overFlowFile));
            mail.Subject = "Weekly Inspection";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(//Hidden);
            client.Send(mail);

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (templateStamper != null)
            {
                templateStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                templateStamper.Close();
            }
            if (overFlowStamper != null)
            {
                overFlowStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                overFlowStamper.Close();
            }
            if (templateReader != null)
                templateReader.Close();
            if (overFlowReader != null)
                overFlowReader.Close();

            return "Submit Weekly: " + e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what files are in use by what process on Win7x64. Use Ctrl+F to search by handle or DLL substring, enter the name of the file and it should show usage.

Comment: A [`using` Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) with the `PdfStamper` and `FileStream`  should solve your problem. If you don't need to save the PDF(s), you can replace `FileStream` with a `MemoryStream` to save you the extra step of deleting the file(s) after sending the email attachments.

Comment: @kuujinbo please submit as answer.

Answer (score 0):

A [`using` Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) with the `PdfStamper` and `FileStream` should solve your problem. If you don't need to save the PDF(s), you can replace `FileStream` with a `MemoryStream` to save you the extra step of deleting the file(s) after sending the email attachments.